# Set class variable value, the value returned by a class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm trying to create a class which maps to a mongoDB collection.

My code looks like this:

```
class Collection:
    _collection = get_collection()  # This seems not working

    @classmethod
    def get_collection(cls):
        collection_name = cls.Meta.collection_name if cls.Meta.collection_name \
        else cls.__name__.lower()
        collection = get_collection_by_name(collection_name) # Pseudo code, please ignore
        return collection

    class Meta:
        collection_name = 'my_collection'
```

I came across a situation where I need to assign the class variable `_collection` with the return value of `get_collection`.
I also tried `_collection = Collection.get_collection()` which also seems not to be working

As a work-around, I subclassed `Collection` and set value of `_collection` in the child class.

Would like to know any simple solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Notice that a good linter would have warned you that `get_collection()` is yet undefined where you place it.

Comment: Sorry, mis-typed the function name `get_collection_by_name` to be `get_collection`. Updated the question

Comment: But, what is `get_collection_by_name()`?

Comment: The really simple way is to make the assignment immediately after the class definition, i.e., put `Collection._collection = Collection.get_collection()` as the next line of code after the definition of `Collection`. But I guess Bruno's way makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DeepSpace mentions, here:

```
class Collection:
    _collection = get_collection()  # This seems not working

    @classmethod
    def get_collection(cls):
        # code that depends on `cls`
```

the `get_collection` method is not yet defined when you call it. But moving this line after the method definition won't work either, since the method depends on the `Collection` class (passed as `cls` to the method), which itself won't be defined before the end of the `class Collection:` statement's body.

The solution here is to wait until the class is defined to set this attribute. Since it looks like a base class meant to be subclassed, the better solution would be to use a metaclass:

```
class CollectionType(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        super(CollectionType, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
        cls._collection = cls.get_collection()


# py3
class Collection(metaclass=CollectionType):
    # your code here


# py2.7
class Collection(object):
    __metaclass__ = CollectionType
    # your code here
```

Note however that if `Collection` actually inherit from a another class already having a custom metaclass (ie Django `Model` class or equivalent) you will need to make `CollectionType` a subclass of this metaclass instead of a subclass of `type`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out `metaclass`, this was what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

There are some design/syntax errors in your code.

- When the line `_collection = get_collection()` executes, `get_collection` is not yet defined. As a matter of fact, the whole `Collection` class is not yet defined.
- `get_collection_by_name` is not defined anywhere.

**EDIT** OP updated the question so the below points may not be relevant anymore

- `collection = get_collection(collection_name)` should be 
   `collection = cls.get_collection(collection_name)`
- Sometimes you are passing a parameter to `get_collection` and sometimes you don't, however `get_collection`'s signature never accepts a parameter.
- Calling `get_collection` will lead to an infinite recursion.

You have to take a step back and reconsider the design of your class.

Comment: "When the line _collection = get_collection() executes, get_collection is not yet defined. " => and neither is the `Collection` class so  moving this line after the method definition will not worker either

Comment: @DeepSpace I tried moving the statement `_collection = get_collection()` after the method definition. It raises `TypeError: 'classmethod' object is not callable
`

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks buddy